# How to retrieve IAM Policies attached to an IAM Role with Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to get the attached Policies from an existing IAM Role, I want to reuse existing Policies by just referencing an IAM Role ARN or Name.

So far I can only see a Data Source resource in Terraform called "aws_iam_role" which has an attribute "assume_role_policy" which I don't think its what I'm looking for.

I also see this data source "aws_iam_policy" but that just pulls an individual iam policy, not based on any IAM Role attribute (name, arn, etc).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't appear to be something supported by Terraform at this time. I think the best you could do is use the AWS CLI to lookup the policy ARNs before calling Terraform, and pass those as variables into Terraform. You *might* be able to look those up using the lower-level AWS Cloud Control Terraform provider https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-awscc

Comment: If your intent is reuse of the policies by role membership, is there a reason why you can't just have your resource assume that role?

Comment: There are some roles for EC2 that I would like to load for EKS. AWS CLI might be an option but I'm running my pipelines in Terraform Cloud which doesn't support aws cli. For now I'm just collecting all the individual Policies ids/documents into a single TF Variable.